# Can ITEXTG (iText port for Android/GAE) do html to pdf?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, itext

Can [ITEXTG](http://www.itextpdf.com/product/itextg) (iText port for Andriod/GAE) do html to pdf?

If not any other suggestions for html to pdf on Java Google App Engine?

Answer (score 1):

Combined with XmlWorker, yes.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlworker/